Is “No Time To Die” the first Bond film to feature children?
I have just watched the entire Bond franchise from beginning to end and the most recent film, No Time To Die (2021), is the only one to feature children as far as I can recall. Specifically:

 The film opens with a flashback scene Madeleine Swann as a child where Safin kills her mother, she shoots him, and he saves her from under the ice.

 Mathilde Swan, Medeleine and Bond's daughter features prominently in the last two-thirds of the film; including being in peril.

Now, there may have been children in background scenes - the series would often give us a scene to set a location, which may have had children in the background - however, I can't recall any specific instance.
So, to clarify, before No Time To Die, was there a Bond film to have a child:

In a speaking part?
As a character Bond interacts with?
As an extra in a scene?
In the background?

And, if not, which films were?

Sayan Jantanarat was 10 years old when he played the urchin ‘elephant boy’ (in The Man with the Golden Gun (1974)) that attempts to help James Bond escape by boat in the Khlong canal chase:



Diamonds are Forever (1971) had children at Circus Circus casino:



There were also Lt. Hip's (unnamed) nieces in The Man with the Golden Gun (1974). Their age is unclear but school uniforms would indicate they were intended to be minors:




Ah! Sayan Jantanarat was invading my mind but when I tried to focus I got him confused with Ke Huy Quan from Indiana Jones.

great answer.  :-)

Might be borderline, depending on where you cut the line between child and adult, but Bibi Dahl is a 16-year old in For Your Eyes Only (1981) (though played by a 22/23-year old). She is described as the ward of Kristatos.
As for interacting with Bond… She certainly makes an enthusiastic attempt, though even Bond is uncomfortable at the age difference:



